# Are all known algorithms for solving NP-complete problems constructive?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete

Are there any known algorithms that correctly output "yes" to an NP-complete problem without implicitly generating a certificate?

I understand that it is straightforward to turn a satisfiability oracle into a satisfying-assignment finder: just iterate over the variables, each time asking the satisfiability oracle to solve the conjunction of that variable with the original problem.

But would such a wrapper ever be useful? Do all sat solvers search over the space of possible assignments?

Or are there some types of NP-complete problems (traveling salesman, subset sum, etc.) in which the solver can, say, exploit a mathematical theorem to prove that a solution must exist? Like doing a proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand it, you are asking two questions: **(1)** are there e.g. SAT algorithms that are more clever than naive brute force, and **(2)** are there algorithms that simply give a YES/NO answer when solving an NP-complete problem without actually *finding* the solution. I'll answer both questions in this order.

**(1)** It is perfectly possible to solve a problem without brute force, i.e. without naively trying all possibilities. To take your example, modern complete SAT solvers *can* apply clever algorithms that infer or prove certain (partial) assignments can't lead to a solution, so they don't even examine that part.

More generally, even NP-hard problems often exhibit some kind of algorithmic foothold that allows us to design algorithm faster than brute force. The field of this research is *exact (exponential) algorithms*. Such algorithms take exponential time, but are still faster than naive algorithms. For instance, you can solve TSP in roughly $n!$ time, where $n$ is the number of cities to visit. This method won't scale to even moderate values of $n$, but there is a classic dynamic programming $O(2^nn^2)$ time algorithm due to [Held & Karp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms). For general techniques, see e.g. [branch & bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound).

**(2)** There are "oracle algorithms" for NP-complete problems that just output YES/NO with no explicit certificate. For instance, consider the $k$-path problem:

> **(The $k$-path problem)** Given a graph $G$ and an integer $k$, is there a simple path in $G$ on $k$ vertices?

The above problem is easily seen to be NP-complete. An $O^*(2^k)$ algorithm for the problem is given in [1]. The algorithm itself only gives a YES/NO answer to the problem, but we can use additional tricks to construct the actual $k$-path itself. More generally, when given such an "oracle algorithm", one can use tools from combinatorial group testing for extracting the witness itself.

---

[1] Williams, Ryan. "Finding paths of length $k$ in $O^*(2^k)$ time." Information Processing Letters 109.6 (2009): 315-318. [publisher link](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019008003396), [PDF](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0807.3026v3)

Comment: Perfect. The k-path paper is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks!